# How could achieve this jquery code in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have coded in jquery to find the class and its children to create timelime. same thing i want to do it React. The jquery code is below .. Thanks in advance

the below are the working code from jquery.. how to do the same in React.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var timelines = $('#trip-timeline0'),
      eventsMinDistance = 120;
      //alert(timelines);
    (timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

    function initTimeline(timelines) {
      timelines.each(function(){
        var timeline = $(this),
          timelineComponents = {};

        //cache timeline components 
        timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'] = timeline.find('.events-wrapper');
        timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].children('.events');
        timelineComponents['fillingLine'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].children('.filling-line');
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a');
        timelineComponents['timelineDates'] = parseDate(timelineComponents['timelineEvents']);
        timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'] = minLapse(timelineComponents['timelineDates']);
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'] = timeline.find('.cd-timeline-navigation');
        timelineComponents['eventsContent'] = timeline.children('.events-content');

        //assign a left postion to the single events along the timeline
        setDatePosition(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
        //assign a width to the timeline
        var timelineTotWidth = setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
        //the timeline has been initialize - show it
        timeline.addClass('loaded');

      });
    }
});
```

and what i have now in React so far

```
componentDidMount() {
  var tripline = 'document.getElementById("trip-timeline1")';
  var eventsMinDistance = 50;
  //alert(tripline.length);
  //console.log("Not k",tripline.length,"--",tripline);

  if(tripline.length  > 0){
    iniTripline(tripline, eventsMinDistance); 
    }


  function iniTripline(tripline, eventsMinDistance){

      var triplineComponents = {};
      //cache tripline components 
      triplineComponents['triplineWrapper'] = document.querySelector('.events-wrapper');
      triplineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = document.querySelector('.events');

}
}
```

how to convert the same in React...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just added @LMulvey

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
shouldComponentUpdate(){
return false;
}
```

It'll stop re-rendering the component and let JQuery to takeover the control. 
But if you need to use react functionality after the first mount, you'll have to force re-render ("this.forceUpdate()" which will skip "shouldComponentUpdate()")
Then you can add your code inside componentDidMount.